# minum SDK cannot be less than of a 3ed party library

Tags: android, sdk

My app's minimum SDK version is 16 and I want it to stay that way, recently I tried to implement a 3rd party library that uses SDK version 19
is there any solution to keep the minum SDK at 16 and use the library at the same time ? or I have to give up one of them ?

Comment: Your minimum SDK must be 19 then, you cant say that your minimum SDK is 16 if you cant use it with a API 16 device, and if you are using a library with api level 19 you cant use it with less so you wont be able to use your app with a lower level.

Comment: Unless you manage to make them change it

Comment: 16, 17 and 18 are not that significant, they are 2.4%, 3.5% and 1.0%
api 19 and above have more devices (hell, api 19 alone have more devices that these 3 combined), any special reason to use api <19?
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: if library is not supporting lower version(16 in your case) than you can not implement its functions. you have two options than 1> change your lower version to library version supported
2> change library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this link -
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Override  for imported libraries -

By default, when importing a library with a minSdkVersion value that's higher than the main manifest file, an error occurs and the library cannot be imported. To make the merger tool ignore this conflict and import the library while keeping your app's lower minSdkVersion value, add the overrideLibrary attribute to the  tag. The attribute value can be one or more library package names (comma-separated), indicating the libraries that can override the main manifest's minSdkVersion.

For example, if your app's main manifest applies overrideLibrary like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.app"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="2"
            tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
```

Then the following manifest can be merged without an error regarding the <uses-sdk> tag, and the merged manifest keeps minSdkVersion="2" from the app manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.lib1">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Please test your application throughly to see if the library is producing any errors.

Comment: Sure but if library version is 19 I don't think the author did it just for fun, there can be some code in that library that doesn't work or have bugs in < 19.

Comment: True  , that is why i mentioned to test throughly to make sure that nothing serious comes up.

Comment: Much appreciated, I will try your proposed solution and do the necessary tests